# Kendo ui mobile set default theme to flat ui

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Im just starting out with kendo ui and am running a very basic example below.

It currently displays as ios but i want to set it to be the flat ui theme all the time. I cant see anything in the demos or documentation which state how to do this.

Can somebody tell me how to change the default theme to the flat design?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Kendo UI Mobile CSS -->
<link href="styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- jQuery JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Kendo UI Mobile combined JavaScript -->
<script src="js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <title>Kendo UI Examples</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Kendo Mobile View -->
<div data-role="view" data-title="test" id="index">
    <!--Kendo Mobile Header -->
    <header data-role="header">
        <!--Kendo Mobile NavBar widget -->
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <span data-role="view-title"></span>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--Kendo Mobile ListView widget -->
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <!--Kendo Mobile Footer -->
    <footer data-role="footer">
        <!-- Kendo Mobile TabStrip widget -->
        <div data-role="tabstrip">
            <a data-icon="home" href="#index">Home</a>
            <a data-icon="settings" href="#settings">Settings</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
<script>
// Initialize a new Kendo Mobile Application
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can override the device/skin in the declaration of the app.

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), { skin: 'flat' });
```

Or you can force everyone into using a Windows Phone looking interface

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), { platform: 'wp8' });
```

See documentation...
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/application#configuration-platform

Answer (score -3):

You need to add a selection of the selected style on your loading page.

```
<link href="styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.mobile.flat.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Btw, I do not know if you need to include the all.css if you specify a theme. You might want to test that.

Comment: You don't need the flat skin CSS as it is included in the all package.

Comment: Also if you don't specify a platform or a skin when instantiating the application, the system will attempt to display the CSS that matches the device and you may not get the results you are wanting.  The CSS is not enough.